# Launch a follow-up Python script(Tkinter Interface) after action

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

After entering a password in the initial Python script, I am trying to launch a follow up Python script given the password is correct. I have created a Tkinter for the password to be entered by the user.

I know I can import functions and scripts, however this is not the path I am trying to go down.

Steps:

1) Enter password into entry field, then press Submit.

2a) If incorrect, dialog box populates

2b) If correct password, then other Python script runs.

EDIT: 
Thank you Jonathan for your response!

The structure of the solution I'm looking for is in two pieces, like below.

```py
Script1.py------------
window = Tk()
button = Button(window, text='OK')
button.config(width=5, height=2, command=somefunctionacceptingordeclining)
<br/>
def somefunctionacceptingordeclining():
    if something == something:
        LaunchScript2("C:/Users/User/Documents/Code/Script2.py")
<br/>
window.mainloop()
<br/>
Script2.py-------------------
<br/>
window = Tk()
def dostuff(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 2):

Good question. I don't know what your code looks like so maybe you could provide it, but what i imagine you want is something like this:

```py
window = Tk()

# set up password 

#button which may accept the password/username
button = Button(window, text='OK')
button.config(width=5, height=2, command=somefunctionacceptingordeclining)

def somefunctionacceptingordeclining():
    if something == something:
        window.quit() #this closes the current window and resumes execution 
                      #where i put RESUME

window.mainloop()
# RESUME:

#by importing the script below here you execute it when the window is closed.
import someotherscript
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not too experienced with Stack/didn't know how to edit comments to add code visually appealing so I edited the original post with what I'm looking for :) hope there's a solution

Comment: So do i understand right that you want a function that executes another python script?

Comment: Yes, a function that can execute another script.